# Excel: Greater than or less than with Countifs

Tags: excel, logical-operators, countif

I currently have a dataset with a Start date and an End date. I am attempting to count the number of customers who are "active" (fall within the start date and end date) during a specified month. According to Excels support site, using Greater than or equal to (or its counterpart) should work with countifs. However, when I input <=L2, Excel does not understand the logical command. Effectively the code I am trying to use is:

```
 =countifs(E:E,<=L2,K:K,>=L2)
```

Note in excel, everything past the first "<" character is "grayed out".

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

COUNTIFS criteria needs to be a literal string:

```
=countifs(E:E,"<=" & L2,K:K,">=" & L2)
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!

Comment: @SeanHolt please come back when the question is 15 minutes old and mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.