# Excel Question/Issue with CountIF Function

Tags: excel

I am working with an Excel sheet that involves tracking dates and I am trying to use the CountIf function to show recent additions over the past 7 days. My function looks like:

*=Countif(G3:M35, >=(TODAY()-7))*

I keep getting an error telling me that the function is incorrect but Excel offers no additional help. I expect this to return the number of entries in the range provided that have dates within the past week and as time goes on, it will automatically adjust based on the current date.

Any suggestions?

Thank you,
Luke H

Comment: Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263173/excel-greater-than-or-less-than-with-countifs , try `=COUNTIF(G3:M35,">="&(TODAY()-7))`